# Configure Varnish with SSL for Drupal 7 application

Tags: apache, ssl, drupal, varnish, mixed-content

I have 2 servers, one running my Drupal 7 application through Apache on RHEL 6 and another server is running Varnish Cache. Apache is configured to run on custom HTTP port 8080. I want this application to run on 9443 port with SSL with Varnish Caching support.

I have tried Stunnel, but the site appears broken as the css are not being loaded. I have tried Nginx for SSL termination but browsers complain that there are mixed content as Drupal is generating URLs for resources with "http://".

Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that according to drupal you are running http, and therefore will also return http links. which causes your mixed content issue. have you set your base_url to https?

Comment: I think that would work, like Nginx listening on port 443 and then is proxy passed to Varnish's port and as Drupal will generate URL based on $base_url all the images and css will be loaded properly. Will check and confirm. Thanks man !